# Switch statements, breaking out of for loop to get back up to switch

Tags: c

I have a switch inside of a main while loop that will run my game. I am trying to break out of my switch in order to go to a different case. Example below explains it better:

```
int j = 0;
While(1){
switch(j){
case 0:  ....
        break;
case 1: 
      for( i =0; i > 100; i++){
       if(lives == 0)
        j = 2;
        break; //this is where I want to break out of my switch to go to case 2. But it         
               //breaks out of my for loop. I do not know how to get around this. Thank 
               //you!
       }
 case 2: //some stuff I want to do
}

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with 5 different languages? This has nothing to do with most of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you only want to hit `case 2` when `lives == 0`. If so, you need to put your `break;` in `{ }` together with the `j = 2;` - this will then only break the loop when `lives == 0`. Then if you place a `break;` at the end of `case 0` you will terminate the switch, and then reenter the switch because of the `while(1)` and then you hit `case 2:`.

And your for loop should properly be `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)` not `for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)`

```
int j = 0;
While(1){
  switch(j){
  case 0:  ....
    break;
  case 1: 
    for( i =0; i < 100; i++){
      if(lives == 0) {
        j = 2;
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
 case 2: //some stuff I want to do
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break out of for and go straight to case 2, then your code should do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your actually on the right track but, as mentioned your loop condition needs to be checked.

```
int j = 0;
While(1){
switch(j){
case 0:  ....
    break;
case 1: 
  for( i =0; i < 100; i++){
    if(lives == 0){
        j = 2;
        break; // Break for
    }
  }
if(j != 2) break; // If no break in the switch's case, then continue to the next case
case 2: //some stuff I want to do
    break;
} //End Switch
} //End While
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a state machine like this:

C#
    bool OnceMore = true;

```
string ProcessState = "Start"
while(OnceMore)
{
   OnceMore = False;
   switch(ProcessState)
   {
      case "Start" :
      {
     // do something
     ProcessState = "Check";
         OnceMore = True;
     break;
      }
      case "Check" :
      {
         // do check
         if( Check == "Ok")
         {
            ProcessState = "Close";
         }
         else // try again
         {
            ProcessState = "Start";
         }
         OnceMore = True;
         break;
      }
      case "Close" :
      {
         // do what you need to return to the caller
         break;
      }
   }
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't break out of multiple break-able scopes, you can only break out of the highest one.

The sloppy 'solution' to this is to use a goto jump.

The real solution is to break your functions into smaller logical bite-sized functions, and then you can break or return as you please. Your for-loop almost certainly should be in its own function, for code-quality and cleanliness purposes.

```
bool doSomethingInALoopWithADescriptiveName(int &var)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(lives_WhichShouldntBeGlobal == 0)
        {
            var = 2;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void myFuncWithADescriptiveName()
{
    int variableWithADescriptiveName = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        switch(j)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                //....
            } break;
            case 1:
            {
                bool continueLooping = doSomethingInALoopWithADescriptiveName(&variableWithADescriptiveName);
                if(!continueLooping)
                {
                    return;
                }
            } break;
            case 2:
            {
                //some stuff I want to do
            } break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Because of the question's tagging issues, I'm not sure what language the question is asking about. My answer is applicable to many languages (and can be summed up as "*Write simple, compact, self-descriptive, and clean code*"), but my code example is in pseudo-C++ but can easily be applied to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(j){
case 0:  ....
    break test;
case 1: 
  for( i =0; i > 100; i++){
   if(lives == 0)
    j = 2;
    break; //this is where I want to break out of my switch to go to case 2. But it         
           //breaks out of my for loop. I do not know how to get around this. Thank 
           //you!
   }
break test;
case 2: //some stuff I want to do
 break test;
}


test://After switch.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the braces around the condition that triggers the next case

```
case 1: 
   for( i =0; i > 100; i++)
   {
       if(lives == 0)
       {
           j = 2;
           break; // This exits the for effectively jumping at the case break

       }
       // I suppose here you have other code to process 
       // that should not be executed if (lives == 0)
   }
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your break is breaking out of the for loop. So you would need to add some additional logic to check if the loop exited early, and then call break again.

Secondly, for(i = 0; i > 100; i++) **will never execute** because i is never > 100.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(lives == 0)
    {
        j = 2;
        quit = true;
        break; //Break out of the loop
    }
}
//Note, if this language is C, control will just fall through to case 2 anyway.
//If C#, you have to add a break at the end of this case regardless
if(quit == true)
{
    break; //Break out of switch
}
```